# Setting a *next list pointer to NULL

Tags: c, list, pointers

I have a list with a few nodes. I'm trying to mark the final node by declaring it's `current->next` value as `NULL`.

So, let's say that my `current` is pointing at the final node. Do the two following code snippets work in a different way, and if yes, how?

```
 current->next = NULL;
```

and

```
 current = current->next;
 current = NULL;
```

I have been experimenting with these for a while now but I cannot really understand what is going on in there. I would say they are doing the same thing, as the second one first points my `current` to where `next` points and then sets it to `NULL`.

**EDIT** : Oh, I understand what the answers are saying, and it looks quite obvious to me too now :).  So if I do not use the first way, but opt to go for `current = current->next` is there a way for me to put the NULL value where I ought to? How can I use my new `current` to point where my old `next` was pointing at?

Comment: Those are entirely different things. Time for a good book perhaps?

Comment: Those are apparently valid statements.  The first will set the field `next` in the node addressed by `current` to null.  The second pair of statements will set `current` to the value of `next` stored in the node addressed by `current`, and then overwrite the value you just placed in `current` with null (making the prior statement useless).  (Methinks you haven't quite gotten the concept of what a pointer is.)

Comment: When it comes to pointers I'm hopeless. I've read quite a few simple tutorials on them and I think I can find my way if I'm dealing with simple pointers to ints or chars but if it gets a tiny bit more complicated I'm instantly lost...

Comment: That's because you're trying to memorize stuff instead of understanding it.  A pointer is very simple -- it contains an address.  It is as different from the thing addressed as a telephone number is different from the phone that it connects to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former snippet assigns the `next` field of the struct pointed to by `current` to `NULL`.  The second snippet makes the `current` pointer point at the `next` field of the struct pointed to by `current` and then sets `current` to `NULL`.

I don't really understand the usefulness of the second unless you have some other way to get a reference to the struct, since you essentially cut yourself off from the struct by losing your pointer to it.

So in the former case:

```
current -> struct
           next -> NULL
```

In the latter case:

```
current -> NULL

           struct
           next -> ????
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its pretty straightforward. I'm not losing my struct as I have it's start pinned to another pointer. I have updated my question. Is it possible for me to turn next to NULL by using current after I have done current = current->next ?

Comment: Sure, but it'd be equivalent to `current->next->next=NULL` which I don't think is what you want.  You're probably going to have to use two pointers -- one to hold `next` and the other to point to `current` so you can change `current`'s `next` to `NULL` without losing your reference.

Comment: Thank you. I used a second variable and I was able to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those are different, and it is the first version that you want.

In the second, you're only changing the value of the local variable `current` (to `NULL`), while the `next` pointer of the final node stays the same (it probably should be initialized to `NULL` in the first place, but maybe that's what you're doing).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can see now the problem with the second part very clearly. That's why I updated my question a bit. I hope you can take a quick look at it.

Comment: If I understand your edit, you want to save the old value of `next` while setting it to `NULL` (i.e. splitting the list in two).  You basically need another variable to do this; something like `next = current->next; current->next = NULL; current = next;` (reminiscient of swapping)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second variable was the trick. I will accept Robert's answer though because he was a tiny bit earlier.